# Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because the version of OS X is too new

Tags: xcode, macos

Xcode 6 beta's won't allow distribution.
since may 2014 you have to use 5.1.1 to distribute apps. 
I only have xcode 5.1

I am about to release an app and I am just wondering if I have to go back to osx 10.9 just to be able to update to xcode 5.1.1 so I can release apps again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly yes, you can currently (July 2014) only submit apps from Mountain Lion or Mavericks, using the latest App Store version of Xcode. Only the GM releases will be able to let you submit apps - at least that's how Apple have done it in the past.

You cannot use beta versions of either OS X or Xcode to submit apps.

You can always install Mavericks and Xcode 5.1.1 on an external drive and use that version to submit. Gives you best of both worlds on the same hardware.

Comment: ended up with a network recovery, because I was stuck on yosemite. (yea no backup). Appreciate the answer thanks. Gave you the green checkmark

Comment: Thanks! I really wish Apple would make these things easier for us. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

[This Post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4135803?tstart=0) seems to work in some cases:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist
rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.appstore.savedState
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore
rm -r /private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.appstore
```

If it doesn't work, you could simply set up a Virtual Machine with 10.9 Guest. (Of course, only on a OSX host without any further Hacks)